# Do I qualify as a "latent Dutch" person?

Tags: dutch-citizens, ancestry

My grandparents were Dutch and emigrated to Australia in 1960 with my mother who was a small child at the time. I was born in Australia in 1980 and my Dad is not Dutch. Does this make me [latent Dutch](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latente_Nederlanders)?
My grandfather never naturalized as Australian, my grandmother eventually did but not until 1990. My mother was Dutch at birth and naturalized in Australia independently of her parents at age 17. She was married to my Dad when I was born.

From my understanding this may make me latent Dutch. Does anyone know what the factors would be in this situation?

Comment: @JanDoggen the Dutch Wikipedia article explains reasonably well: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latente_Nederlanders

Comment: Nicola: did your mother naturalize in Australia? If so, when? If not, were you born before her 28th birthday? Was she married to your father when you were born (if she wasn't, you would have been Dutch from birth)?

Answer (score 1):

It would *appear so. [DutchCitizenship.com](http://www.dutchcitizenship.com/dutch-citizenship/us/0/7) has a 4 point test, that you qualify IF:

> Since 2010 Latent Dutch Citizens can obtain Dutch nationality by
>   following the Option Procedure.
>
> Conditions:
>
> - Born before January 1, 1985
> - Born to a Dutch mother
> - Your mother was a Dutch citizen at the time of your birth.
> - Born to a non-Dutch father
> - No option request has been filed previously

Assuming you've not filed an option request, it would seem you qualify as a latent Dutch citizen.